# vb vb.net strict on using multilevel COM object

Tags: vb.net, com, strict

We made big effort for many years of development to make our VBcode `Strict On`. It's efficient and we try to stick to this. However now we integrated it with external `dll` working as `COM object`. And we are not able to keep option strict on anymore, is there any way round?
Code:

```
Option Strict On                      
Public COMOBJECT As Object            'define variable as Object
COMOBJECT = CreateObject(CLSID)       'dispatch COM server
COMOBJECT.OpenFile                    'do whatever dll registered as com exposes
COMOBJECT.SaveFile                    'it all works with Option Strint Off
COMOBJECT.dowhatever                  'but not with Strict On
```

Error: Option Strict On disallows late binding.

Is there a way we can keep option strict On

Comment: I think this is essentially a duplicate - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/635342/vb-net-turning-option-strict-off-in-line for a possible solution.

Comment: There is a complex answer, and it starts here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645736%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

Comment: @RobS no it's not duplicate. Guy there asks on how to make option Strict Off for part of the code. Her I asko how to make working with COM efficient.

Comment: @Alexander thanks - this shall help.